# Static propery or static readony field

Tags: c#, .net, static, readonly

I have some intialized Property/Fields that are "constant" and I want to know which one of the following line is the best to use :

1. `public static Color MyColor { get { return Color.Red; } }`
2. `public static readonly Color MyOtherColor = Color.Red;`

Is there some runtime differences after (lazy)initialization ?
Are the performance usages differents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Field usage guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta31s3bc(v=vs.71).aspx) recommend using public static read-only fields for predefined object instances.  For example:

```
public struct Color
{
    // this is a predefined immutable instance of the containing Type
    public static readonly Color Red = new Color(0x0000FF);

    ...
}
```

In your case, I'd probably use a property:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // Not a predefined instance of the containing Type => property
    // It's constant today, but who knows, tomorrow its value may come from a 
    // configuration file.
    public static Color MyColor { get { return Color.Red; } }
}
```

**UPDATE**

> It's crystal clear when I see your answer, but using ILSpy in System.Drawing shows me the following code: public static Color Red { get { return new Color(KnownColor.Red); } }

The guidelines linked above (which use Color as an example) are for .NET 1.1 and have possibly evolved.  Personally I don't think you can go wrong by using a property.  [.NET 4.0 Field Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229057) are similar, but use `DateTime.MaxValue` and `DateTime.MinValue` as examples of predefined object instances.

Comment: It's cristal clear when I see your answer, but using ILSpy in System.Drawing show me the following code : 
_public static Color Red {  get { return new Color(KnownColor.Red); } }_

Answer (score 3):

If they are constants, then use a constant:

```
public const Color MyColor = Color.Red;
```

In answer to the question, here's a good read on the msdn forums: [Memory consumption: static fields vs static properties](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/705c7c6f-31c7-4376-b845-12e79dc444b2)

**Edit**:

As Joe pointed out in the comments, `Color` cannot be declared a constant because it is not a compile time constant.

A [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10899557/9664) to this question is answered by Joe.

In the end, there will be no noticeable difference between using a static readonly field vs property. Use whatever fits best with the situation.

Comment: You might want to explain why you *can* use a `const` here.  It's only necessary to use `static readonly` when the expression on the RHS (right hand side) is compile time constant.  Since `Color.Red` is a value, known at compile time, you don't need `static readonly` which is needed when the value requires a `new` or some function to run.  If you don't *know* the color at compile time (because you need to load the preferences) then the value is the result of a function, and `static readonly` is needed.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl - I think you've done a good job at explaining it already ;) +1

Comment: The type System.Drawing.Color can not be declared const.  But even for primitive types, when it is possible, be aware that if the value changes, any assembly that references the constant value will need to be recompiled.

Comment: @Joe - that is one of the 50 from "Effective C#: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your C#". Not that the author was the first to shed light on the topic. Great read.

Comment: Oops, totally just went with it. Education free for everyone!

Answer (score 0):

A few practical considerations:

- If you plan to use the value in a switch statement or expression, it
  must be a const, not a read only field or property.
- You may want to use a read only field as opposed to a constant if you
  plan to use the value it other assemblies.  If you have a constant in
  assembly A and use that constant in assembly B, the constant value gets
  compiled into assembly B.  If you then change the constant and recompile
  only assembly A, then assembly B will still contain the original
  value, and must be recompiled.  This is not the case with a read only
  field because the value will be retrieved from assembly A at runtime.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).